# Divide rows in two columns with Pandas

Tags: pandas, division

I am using Pandas.

1. For each row, regardless of the County, I would like to divide "AcresBurned" by "CrewsInvolved".
2. For each County, I would like to sum the total AcresBurned for that County and divide by the sum of the total CrewsInvolved for that County.

I just started coding and am not able to solve this. Please help. Thank you so much.

```
Counties AcresBurned  CrewsInvolved
1          400                2
2          500                3
3          600                5
1          800                9 
2          850                8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple with Pandas. You could create a new col with these operations.

```
df['Acer_per_Crew'] = df['AcersBurned'] / df['CrewsaInvolved']
```

You could use a groupby clause for viewing the sum of AcersBurned for a county.

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['counties']) ['AcersBurned', 'CrewsInvolved'].sum().reset_index()

df_gb.columns = ['counties', 'AcersBurnedPerCounty', 'CrewsInvolvedPerCounty']

df = df.merge(df_gb, on = 'counties')
```

Once you've done this, you could create a new column with a similar arithmetic operation to divide AcersBurnedPerCounty by CrewsInvolvedPerCounty.